# School website denial of service attack prevention

Tags: hosting, denial-of-service

I have to rely on an external hosting provider for my school website. If more than 10 students collectively log in with incorrect login details the hosting provider will launch a denial of service attack from where the incorrect loggings originated. i.e. from within the school. So this means the school will be logged out of its own resource.

Students will get their logging in details incorrect sometimes, and they also need to log in at the same time. So I do not know how to get around this problem.

Does anyone have any ideas, as it appears that I cannot get a hosting account which will avoid this from happening, and we do not have the money for an internal webserver where the settings for security can be controlled. We have been quoted £28K for one of these!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear here if you have hosted your website under shared hosting and what is (may by anti-DDoS software) causing DDoS trigger. If maximum number of concurrent users is known, you can ask web hosting provider to tweak their DDoS prevention software to allow same number of concurrent failed attempts. As an alternative, you can choose other Web Hosting type such VPS. In VPS, you will have full administrative access. So by default there is no anti DDoS software or firewall that can trigger false DDoS alerts. If you wish you can tweak/disable or enable it.